# concatenating TimeSeries of different lengths using Pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, concatenation, pandas

I am using `pandas` in python.  I have several Series indexed by dates that I would like to concat into a single DataFrame, but the Series are of different lengths because of missing dates etc.  I would like the dates that do match up to match up, but where there is missing data for it to be interpolated or just use the previous date or something like that.  What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: you should add some example data in your question to make it clearer and easier to answer based on your example.

Answer (score 1):

If the Series are in a dict `data`, you need only do:

`frame = DataFrame(data)`

That puts things into a DataFrame and unions all the dates. If you want to fill values forward, you can call `frame = frame.fillna(method='ffill')`.

Comment: I tried using frame = DataFrame(data) but then it says that " If use all scalar values, must pass index". I tried passing in the dates with frame = DataFrame(data, index = 1), it flags an error. I am using a for loop to loop to get data off of yahoo finance.